# Avoid multiple form submission via ajax request before first ajax call completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that I am submitting via ajax call. But when the user click form submit button more than one time then ajax call runs each time before first ajax call completion.
So I want to stop multiple submission until the first call is complete.
Here is my ajax call.

```
jQuery('#form1').submit(function(){
   var form_data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
   form_data = JSON.stringify(form_data);
   var url = 'My ajax URL';
       jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:url,
            data: {
              'data': form_data
            },
            success: function(data){
              alert('success');
            }
        });
})
```

Comment: I would suggest the easiest way - lock form button after click and once the response return from server than unlock it. Additionally you can check debounce function in lodash: "Creates a debounced function that delays invoking func until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time the debounced function was invoked." https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce

Comment: You can do it with a synchronous (non-async) request **async: false** parameter, but it's generally a bad thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply disable your submit button.

E.g. you have a button with ID `mySubmitButton`

```
jQuery('#form1').submit(function(){
   $('#mySubmitButton').prop('disabled', true); /* <-- disable button */
   var form_data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
   form_data = JSON.stringify(form_data);
   var url = 'My ajax URL';
       jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:url,
            data: {
              'data': form_data
            },
            success: function(data){
              $('#mySubmitButton').prop('disabled', false); /* <-- enable button */
              alert('success');
            }
        });
})
```

Side note: You should also have an error function on service calls, always, and you should enable your button in there too.

Answer (score 2):

You need a flag to keep track of the submit status.

```
var isSubmitting = false; // the flag

jQuery('#form1').submit(function(){
   // If the form is currently being processed, return.
   if (isSubmitting) {
    return; // Do nothing and return
   }
   var form_data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
   form_data = JSON.stringify(form_data);
   var url = 'My ajax URL';
   isSubmitting = true;
   jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:url,
        data: {
          'data': form_data
        },
        success: function(data){
          alert('success');
        },
        complete: function () {
          // After everything is complete, reset the flag so the form can be submitted again later if needed.
          isSubmitting = false;
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

once the submit button get clicked you can disable it until the ajax call get done then simply remove the disable attribute

```js
jQuery('#form1').submit(function(){
   $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
   var form_data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
   form_data = JSON.stringify(form_data);
   var url = 'My ajax URL';
       jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:url,
            data: {
              'data': form_data
            },
            success: function(data){
              alert('success');
            }
        }).done(function() {
        $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
        });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show loader after Click event of your button which will disable the keyboard events as follow

```
jQuery('#form1').submit(function(){
$('[id*=loadingmodal]').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });//show the loader after click
   var form_data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
   form_data = JSON.stringify(form_data);
   var url = 'My ajax URL';
       jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:url,
            data: {
              'data': form_data
            },
            success: function(data){
              alert('success');
 $('[id*=loadingmodal]').modal('hide');//hide the loader after completion
            }
        });
})
```

see following image of loader after click event
[Loader Image Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3iFS.png)

following design shows simple loading modal of bootstrap and CSS

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="loadingmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
            <div class="modal-content" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; margin-left: -100px; margin-top: -150px; padding: 0px">
                <div class="modal-body" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
                    <div class="loader">
                        <div class="loader-inside"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```